# How to map the dict it contains two values?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am not able to match the dict values with dict keys because for some dict contains two values.

```
my_dict = {
    'Incident':'INC, Incident',
    'Minor Enchancement':'Change',
    'ServiceRequest':'SR, ServiceRequest'
}
```

input:

```
new_list= ['Incident','Inc','SR','Change']
```

output:

```
    new_list = ['Incident','Incident','Minor Enchancement','Service Request']
```

i want read the list and match with dictionary . some key contains two values in the dictionary how can we match dict ?

Comment: How is this related to pandas or dataframes?

Comment: Your dict entries do NOT contain two values.  They each contain one string value.  Perhaps you want to do `.split(', ')` on your values before you search.  Note that it would be more efficient to have the KEY be the words you want to search for, and the VALUES be the correct substitition.

Comment: You give inputs and outputs, but not the code that produced one from the other. Where's the [MCVE] that actually behaves this way?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better organization:

```
xlate = {
    'INC': 'Incident',
    'Inc': 'Incident',
    'Change': 'Minor Enhancement',
    'SR': 'ServiceRequest'
}

words = ['Incident','Inc','SR','Change']

new_list = []
for w in words:
    new_list.append( xlate.get(w, w) )
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
['Incident', 'Incident', 'ServiceRequest', 'Minor Enhancement']
```

Note that I use `.get(w,w)` which will pass "not found" entries through unchanged.

Comment: I am reading the data from the database so i am making as dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You want to invert the keys and values in the original dictionary, and split the values to produce multiple keys:

```
my_dict = {
    'Incident':'INC, Incident, Inc',  #note that I added another alias
    'Minor Enchancement':'Change',
    'ServiceRequest':'SR, ServiceRequest'
}

reversed_dict = {}
for key in my_dict:
    items = [x.strip() for x in my_dict[key].split()]
    for i in items:
        reversed_dict[i] = key

assert reversed_dict['Incident'] == 'Incident'
assert reversed_dict['Inc'] == 'Incident'
```

Note that there is no 'magic' way to navigate between using `Inc` and `INC`, so if you want to be able to handle either case you need to include them as options.